# Laravel 5.1, how to have a dynamic database connection in model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I`m using a self created package. This package includes some models. These models should connect to the APP database, but because its a package, the database names can be different.

To solve this, my package includes a config file, where the database name(connection name) is stored.

In the config file:

`return [ 'app_model_db_connection' => 'first_database' ];`

This works fine, i can grab the config value by doing: `Config::get('myconfig.app_model_db_connection);`

Now i wanted to do this in my model:

`protected $connection = \Config::get('package_customview.app_model_db_connection');`

But this does not work. The error:
`syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'`

Looks like i can only add a string after `$connection =` . Because when i do: `protected $connection = "first_database"` , it works. But i want to grab this value from my config file. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you'd just have to put it in the constructor of the model.

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->connection = \Config::get('package_customview.app_model_db_connection');
}
```

Comment: No problem.  If you need to do this on all of your models, you might want to create a `BaseModel` with this constructor which extends `Model`.  Then all your models can just extend the `BaseModel`.